# Run time error '9' ,Subscript out of range error

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel and VBA programming, I have made attendance sheet and want to copy data from one sheet to other ( month wise) by pressing button.

I am getting error at the following line

`lastrow1 = Sheets(“Sheet14”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

**My code**

```
Sub Button2_Click()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
    Dim myname As String
    lastrow1 = Sheets(“Sheet14”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 7 To lastrow1
        myname = Sheets(“Sheet14”).Cells(i, “A”).Value

        Sheets(“sheet2”).Activate
        lastrow2 = Sheets(“sheet2”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For j = 7 To lastrow2

            If Sheets(“sheet2”).Cells(j, “A”).Value = myname Then
                Sheets(“Sheet14”).Activate
                Sheets(“Sheet14”).Range(Cells(i, “D”), Cells(i, “AH”)).Copy
                Sheets(“sheet2”).Activate
                Sheets(“sheet2”).Range(Cells(j, “D”), Cells(j, “AH”)).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
            End If

        Next j
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
    Sheets(“Sheet14”).Activate
    Sheets(“Sheet14”).Range(“D7”).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: @YowE3K  You're right, I've noticed afterwards , thanks :)

Comment: lastrow2 = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Sheets("sheet2").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Answer (score 0):

Your code had the wrong type of `“` , instead of `"`.

It's better to stay away from `Activate` , `Select` and `ActiveSheet` and use referenced Worksheet and Ranges instead (it will also be faster).

Try the code below, it will do the same, just a little faster (and more reliable not depending on the `ActiveSheet`.

**Modified Code**

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
Dim myname As String

With Sheets("Sheet14")
    lastrow1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' take the line below outside the For loop, there is no need to get the last row evey time 
    lastrow2 = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Sheets("sheet2").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row        
    For i = 7 To lastrow1
        myname = .Range("A" & i).Value

        For j = 7 To lastrow2
            If Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & j).Value = myname Then
                .Range("D" & i & ":AH" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Range(Range("D" & j & ":AH" & j))
            End If
        Next j
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

**Note**: if the data in sheet2 and sheet14 are unique (appear only once in  the entire sheet) consider using the `Match` function, it will save you 1 `For` loop.

Comment: @Kanan I've just tested it now and it works for me, are you sure you have "sheet2" in your workbook ? spelled like this ?

Comment: @Kanan you copied my entire code from above ? all of it ? with al; `"` and not your `“` and still got this error ? can't trace it, sorry

Comment: @Kanan ok, but please open  a chat

Comment: @Kanan it's somewhere here in SO

Comment: I have not earn reputation for chat...not eligible...as this is first time.If you can provide me your email id I can send you file.